# How to change element CSS class when different part of web page is present?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I hope it works like this:

suppose there is a long web page and its content has two parts: "content of index 1" and "content of index 2". And my PC screen can only present one part. Also there is a list of 2 items on the side of the page with every item indicating one part of the web page.

What I want is I will set item1 with CSS class 'live' when part 1 is present in the screen; and I will set item2 with CSS class 'live' when part 2 is present in the screen (on the same time, I will remove 'live' from item 1).

To be clear, just like this website's implementation.

http://v2.bootcss.com/components.html

Thanks,

Comment: You should edit your question to write most comprehensive one

Comment: Your question is not really clear but il you work with classes and if your are working on same html element you can "combine" classes like this `.index1.live` (no space)

Comment: thanks for your comments! I have edited my question again, hope it is clear to you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By further reading, this is the functionality of BootStrap.

For Chinese tutorial, maybe W3C school provides the best one - http://www.w3cschool.cc/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy-plugin.html

The specific component is "ScrollSpy"